# Как хранить пользовательские данные (изображения)?

Tags: архитектура, php, проектирование, вконтакте, хранение-данных

Как хранить пользовательские данные (изображения). Как это утроено у VK?
Есть ли какие-то технологии сжатия фото и прочее?
Сейчас все работает банально просто - загрузка фотографии от пользователя в общую папку photo с уникальным именем файла

Comment: в вк, мне кажется, cdn хранилище быстро просто удобно, работает пока у тебя есть бабло.

Comment: Давайте будем последовательны. В чём конкретно проблема нынешнего банального способа, и какая проблема, думаете, может возникнуть через год?